# Using (this) without the anchor tag

Tags: jquery, mobile, this, nav

Currently have a mega menu with a structure of:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="level-top">Link 1</a>
    <ul class="subnav">Subnav</ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="level-top">Link 2</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>
        <a>Link 1 Level 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-subnav"></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When link 1 is selected I want the ul.subnav to display. Currently the code im using is:

```
jQuery('.mobile-nav li a.level-top').click(function () {
  togglePanel(jQuery(this).find('ul.subnav'));
});
```

The first level (subnav) opens correctly if I remove **a.level-top** from the jquery code above. However because i'd be appending the click event to the li element, I couldn't have an accordion toggle deeper into the navigation as the elements are nested within the li element.

I need to append the click function to the anchor tag (a.level-top) but then **(this)** would not find the correct submenu to open.

Any way of using **this - anchor tag?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.next()`, not `.find()`:

```
jQuery('.mobile-nav li a.level-top').click(function () {
  togglePanel(jQuery(this).next('ul.subnav'));
});
```

The reason is, `ul.subnav` is a sibling of `<a>` and not a child of `<a>`. The `.find()` is used to get the child.